# Broadcasting a webcam feed

Tags: video-streaming, webcam, red5

I am looking to setup a stream from my home webcam and I am wondering if someone can point me in a good direction.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a "home security" type project [WebCamXP 5](http://www.webcamxp.com/) might do the trick. It has an inbuilt server you can you access multiple camera feeds over the network or internet. As you've not tagged the post with your OS I'm presuming it's Windows.

Bear in mind residential homes have notoriously poor upload speeds and you may find the video stream is unwatchable.

Answer (score 1):

I picked up a [Linksys WVC54GCA](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/wireless/lbc/WVC54GCA) and I watch the mp4 feed using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).  You can watch it remotely by just accessing http://yourdomain.com/img/video.asf.  You can hand out the same URL to other people if you want them to watch the feed.

Answer (score 0):

So this is from a home broadband connection right? how many viewers are you anticipating and what player software are you expecting them to watch it with at what resolution?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, you can *easily* broadcast using VLC, (just look in the manual page)

...

or you can download a utility called webcam-server from the debian/ubuntu repositories, or get it from the sourceforge page here:  http://webcamserver.sourceforge.net/

I've been using this one and it was simple, works just fine.